# Biblical figures in the Kabbalah

Tags: tanach, mysticism-kabbalah

I am seeking to understand the kabbalistic meanings of the following biblical persons:

1) Esav. Does he represent tohu chesed or klippot chesed?

2) Lot.

Would appreciate Sources With Your answer.

Comment: "Does he represent tohu chesed or klippot chesed?" Why are those the two choices? BTW, those two choices aren't mutually-exclusive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Baal HaTanya in [Torah Or](http://chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/toraor/3/11d) describes Lot as:

> קודם הבירור הי' לוט כלול באברהם בקדושה כמו סיגים אשר קודם הצירוף ובירור מעורבים הם עם זהב. ולו"ט בגי' מ"ה אחורי' דשם מ"ה. אך הוא מקור חו"ב דקליפה לכן נק' לוט לשון קללה ולכן הלך לוט את אברהם קודם הבירור
>
> Before the purification, Lot was included in Avraham in holiness, like the impurities prior to the parting and purification which are mixed in gold. Lot (Lamed Vov Tes) has the numerical value of 45 representing the rear of the Name Mah [A way of spelling out each letter of the Tetragrammon to total a numerical value of 45]. But it (Lot at that level) is the source Chochma and Bina of Klippa, therefore he is called Lot related to the word curse, and therefore Lot traveled with Avraham before the purification.

In that place he alludes to Eisav having a similar relationship to Yitzchak. In [another place](http://www.chabadlibrary.org/books/adhaz/toraor/6/20b) he expands on that. Quite a bit more technical than the above, but in summary Esav represents the level of Klippah which allows energy to be drawn from Kedusha without being affected by it - the 11th level, whereas Sefiros in Kedusha number 10 only.

Comment: Which sphere would be the 11th level? Da'at is sometimes referred to as the 11th sefirot, or non-sefirot, but not because in order from top to bottom, or bottom to top, it is 11th, but rather because sometimes it's not included and the other 10 are. Jacob is most referenced as Tiferet, so if you look at it from the opinions and chronology (like before selling the birthright) where Esau is the firstborn, then Esau could be Da'at (one above Tiferet), or Geburah (the sphere that emanates before Tiferet, but on the left). Or, if Esau is 2nd born after Jacob, then either Malkut or Netzach?

Comment: But that is only one way of looking at it, a family Tree of Isaac, and in that case you can also ask why then would the first born not be Chokhmah and the second born either Binah or, if a male could not be Binah, then Da'at. Or you can look at it not as the family tree of Isaac at all, but all the way back to Adam, in which case there are too many sons and daughters to fit in ten spheres, but each sphere has another ten within it infinitely so it could work on that basis.

There are many opinions, I dont remember them all, that's why I ask.

Comment: @ShipBuilding. It isn't one of the 10 (whichever system is used - include Daas or include Keser). It is a surrounding level above the 10. I've seen a name for it, but I don't recall it offhand.

Answer (score 2):

The discussion offered by @Yishai above is accurate. For a detailed discussion of the concept of Lot and his two daughters, see Likuttei Torah of Chaim Vital, parshat Vayera, the discourse, "And Sarah denied that she laughed" starting from paragraph 6.

As mentioned in Meori Ohr, Letter Lamed, chapter 27, it emphasizes 'cursed' and not 'to curse'. Lot is cursed because his two daughters become for him the parallel to Leah and Rochel for Yaacov. Meaning they become his wives.

Esav on the other hand is associated with the nachash in Meori Ohr, Letter Ayin, chapter 68. Esav עשו, is נחש חי, living serpent. He is also related to his ministering angel on the side of klippah, Samael (סמאל). This is because the letter Samech is exchanged with the letter Shin. Then include the letters and kollel.

This function of the nachash is relating to the nachash of kedusha, meaning before the sin in the Garden of Eden. This is also discussed at length in Leshem Shevo v'Achlama, Sefer Deah.

Comment: any source for that Samael is related to Smol (left) through interchange of sin and samech

Comment: @user813801 Do you mean aside from the basic grammatical exchange? If you look in a Jastrow Hebrew-English dictionary, there are thousands of examples.

Comment: Is that discourse ("And Sarah denied that she laughed") available in english, and is Leshem Shevo v'Achlama, Sefer Deah available in english? It's better to read in Hebrew but since I still can't, I would much appreciate it in english.

Where can I learn more about the teaching of the nachash of kedusha before the sin in the Garden? I posted a question about that (interpretations where the serpent is parallel to Jacob, rather than parallel to Esau) but it got no responses.This sounds more like an interpretation where its still parallel Esau, but in holiness pre-sin. Hope to better understand

Comment: @ShipBuilding To my knowledge, neither of these sources is available in English (especially reliable) translation.